# Submitting iPhone app for a client

Tags: ios

I have an existing apple ID connected to my own iTunes Connect account.  Now I need to submit an app for a client.  I am unclear as to the process.  They were unable to add my existing apple ID to their iTunes Connect account.  So we created a new apple ID, I can now get in to manage applications but I am unable to create a bundle ID or provisioning profiles, which means I cannot submit the app within their iTunes connect account...Is this because this new apple ID needs to pay the fee to join the developer program in order to submit applications?  Seems unfair if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have to pay Apple's developer fee to submit an application. Specifically, if the client wants their name to be listed as the manufacturer of the application, they will need to set up their own account.

Comment: My client has paid the developer program fee and does have an account, but I need access to the program portal which their admin user has, but I do not.  Does it seem fair that I would need to pay more than once for the privilege to submit applications - once for my own company and once for them?

Comment: The idea is that you have a license you use for development and the client has one for distribution. If you had, say, 10 clients then you would still only need 1 account for yourself (but each client would still need their own). I don't know whether or not it's fair, but unfortunately that's just how it works :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use send .ipa to client .The best option is use testflighapp.com. you can signup and use it.